# How to use 3rd party dll in Objective c xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, soap, dll

Is their a way for using an existing c++ compile dll in an objective c xcode project.

I dont have access to the c++ code, but i have documentation that tell me about the methods i can use.

I did some research regarding this and found few suggestions like creating a WRAPPER for those dll's in Objective c++ or something like that.

I am relatively new to Objective c and still learning it. So any help in layman terms would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. You say DLL, which makes it sound like it's a Windows library, yet you are using Xcode, which makes it sound like you're making something for Mac/iOS. Could you elaborate a little on which platforms you're working with; possibly also the DLL in question?

Comment: @zenzelezz, i am making an iPhone app on xcode. Now the dll i am talking about are from a c++ product.

Comment: Does the file actually have the .dll extension?  If so, it's an MS Windows library and won't be usable at all.  In fact, to be usable, the library would have to have been built for iPhone.  In other words, if it's built for a Mac, you can't use it on an iPhone.  You mention SOAP as a tag.  Is the library SOAP-related?

Comment: @OmniProg, the extension is .dll and yes it cannot be used directly. But is their any indirect way of using it.
I mentioned SOAP as their are web services available for the product whose dll's i am trying to use.
I am keeping web services as last option if i dont have any other way of using these dll's.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to use a Windows DLL in an iOS/Mac OS X project. :(  Sorry.  Assuming no binary distributions for your platform or source distributions, you are stuck with their web services.  Well, if you really wanted to keep things independent of their services, you could write an app running on a Windows platform and exposing the DLL's functionality in some way to your iOS-based app.  But this is kind of extreme.  You can probably find another library with similar functionality that provides more than a DLL and SOAP interface.